# How do I uppercase using ItemStringFormat in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose I have a combobox where items are binded to an array of strings. I want to use ItemStringFormat to display those strings in uppercase. How do I do that?

Update: I'm not completely clueless about formatting strings, but I've searched MSDN for a format specifier that will turn a string to uppercase, and for some reason I just can't find it! I would have expected it to be something like "{0:U}" or "{0:S}" or something like that.

I also can't believe I wasn't able to find the answer here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a **Converter as part of your binding**. It is trivial to build a class that implements **IValueConverter** which simply returns

```
  return ((string)value).ToUpper();
```

Comment: The thought had occurred to me, but it seemed very clumsy to do. I was 99.99% sure there was a simple format specifier for this. It seems like overkill to have to create a new converter just for this.

Comment: Nonetheless, if no one else knows of a magic format specifier, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, it is not possible. However it is simple to achieve what you a `DataTemplate` and a value converter.

**Example**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:StringToUpperCaseConverter x:Key="ToUpperConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding YourCollection}>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Path=YourValue, Converter="{StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<ComboBox>
```

**Converter**

```
public class StringToUpperCaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((string)value).ToUpper();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
    }
}
```

There is lots of information available on both of these topics on the internet and in *any* WPF book.

Comment: I'm pretty well versed in converters. In fact, I'm knee deep in converters, and I wanted to avoid having one more for something this trivial. I think it's odd and frustrating that there is no simple format specifier.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, however sometimes it not possible. Another approach would be change the data in your ViewModel.

Comment: I have wanted to try Josh Smith's converter chaining implementation (it is on his blog). It is really cool as then you write really simple converters and chain them together to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't just use `.ToUpper();` ?

Comment: I can't. I have to fill in a value for ItemStringFormat. It's declarative code, not in the code behind.